# Drupal JQuery UI Draggable / Stacking Divs

Tags: drupal, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to get the jquery draggable function to work, particularly the stacking feature, in Drupal. I've got the JQuery UI module installed and it works fine with a hide/reveal sliding box but not for the draggable?

Here's what I've got in the body of my page:

```
<?php
drupal_add_js('
$(document).ready(function drag() {
  $(".cc-drag").draggable();
});','inline');
?>

<div class="cc-drag">
    <div class="cc_top">
    <div class="cc_content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque elit dolor, ornare non vulputate quis, dictum ut neque. 
    Nunc non velit at nulla posuere pulvinar. Maecenas vitae diam iaculis lorem sagittis condimentum et at elit. 
    Praesent ac augue dolor. 
    Sed sit amet orci leo, vitae sagittis ante. 
    Phasellus id volutpat nibh. 
    Nam ullamcorper mi at urna cursus vitae aliquet est ullamcorper.
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="cc_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using Drupal 6.x on WAMP.

Thanks!

Comment: Chrome gives this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'draggable'

Does that mean the method is missing in the Jquery UI?

Comment: try to execute this in a js console in your browser: `typeof $().draggable`. It should return "function" if draggable is available.

Comment: thanks googletorp, i'm getting this in firebug $(".cc-drag").draggable is not a function

Comment: but ui.draggable.js is in my \sites\all\modules\jquery_ui\jquery.ui\ui directory. any ideas what i'm missing?

Comment: i included the js files in my site theme, still nothing, just errors.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'draggable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the js files weren't loading, or not loading fully, so I copied the ones I needed to my theme folder and linked to them in my .info file.

```ini
scripts[] = js/jquery.ui.widget.js 
scripts[] = js/jquery.ui.mouse.js 
scripts[] = js/jquery.ui.core.js 
scripts[] = js/jquery.ui.draggable.js
```

The order they are loaded is important. I found many many other threads and forums where other people have been having the same problem in the last 1-4 months. Hope this helps someone else. The js console in firebug was really helpful in getting to the root of the errors, if anyone needs to explore their own problem further.

Answer (score 3):

In **Drupal 7**, where jQuery UI is in core:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.draggable');
```

See http://drupal.org/node/1001508

In **Drupal 6**:

```
jquery_ui_add(array('ui.draggable'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the preferred method:

```
jquery_ui_add(array('ui.draggable', 'ui.resizable', 'ui.dialog'));
```

Just place that in your module's `hook_init()` function.